# Change payment status type?

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal

We have a customer where we want to change the payment status after the IPN has been received.

Mostly we want to enable all payment settings for paypal orders. Right now there is only the currently logical payment status in the order overview.

Under System -> Order statuses we've got several statuses that are not linked to any state.

How can I enable them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On **Order Status** screen click **"Assign Status To State"** button. Select Status and State respectively and click **Save Status Assignment** button. All done.[image]

Comment: Does an upgrade rest those settings?

Comment: Elaborate your question please!

Comment: We've updated the shop recently (yesterday). Since then no usual payment status where visible in the order configuration window. We now are facing the problem that the customer cannot assign "complete" to his order. Any idea how we can fix this?

Comment: When customer places an order the order status will be either pending or processing as per your settings and payment status. Now to complete the order for a physical product you need to click Ship button and complete the form.

Comment: Ah, not here. Customer is using a ERP for his orders, so this should be done automatically at some point; however: he told me that he does that manually for all orders. No change intended. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯